# A problem with list of figures/ tables

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using a class file based on [USFdissertation.cls](http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~saito/grad/USFDissertation.cls), and my problem is that in the list of tables and figures, it does not print the words "Table" or "Figure" before their titles, even though according to its class file it should.

In order to run the code, please replace the whole section regarding table of contents in the `.cls` file with the following code:

```
%%%%%% The TABLE OF CONTENTS and friends
%%%
%%% \@dottedtocline would be level (indentation), [width one]
%%% label, [width two]
%%% number, ... forming hbox to the left, [width three]
%%% title, and leaders forming vbox in the middle, [width four]
%%% page number, forming hbox to the right [width 5]
%%% it is decidedly simpler to accept \@dottedtocline as given,
%%% and instead add \hspace*'s in title to force proper alignment
%%%
%%%%%%

\newcommand\@pnumwidth{.3in} 
\newcommand\@tocrmarg{0.5in} 
\newcommand\@dotsep{.5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}    \vskip 0.5em \@plus.2\p@ % 2 -> 3
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\linespacingfactor}
  \normalfont
  \chapter*{\contentsname\@mkboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}}
  \setlength\@tempparfillskip{\parfillskip}
  \setlength\@templeftskip{\leftskip}
  \setlength\@temprightskip{\rightskip}
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} 
  \normalfont
  \@starttoc{toc}%
  \setlength\parfillskip{\@tempparfillskip}
  \setlength\leftskip{\@templeftskip}
    \vskip 0.5em \@plus.2\p@
  \setlength\rightskip{\@temprightskip}
  \typeout{\men@me: Bolded TOC}
  \newpage
}
\newcommand*\l@lot%[2]
  {\vskip 1.48em \@plus.2\p@
   \@dottedtocline{0}{0in}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@lof{%
  \vskip 1.48em \@plus.2\p@\@dottedtocline{0}{0in}{2.3em} 
  }
\newcommand*\l@abstract{%
  \vskip 1em \@plus.2\p@\@dottedtocline{0}{0in}{2.3em}
  }
\newcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{.25em \@plus\p@}%
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
  \@restonecolfalse
  \chapter*{\listfigurename
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{lof}{\listfigurename}{\thepage}}
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
  \@starttoc{lof}%
  \typeout{\men@me: Bolded LOF}
}
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       { #1}\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\newlength{\@tempparfillskip}
\newlength{\@templeftskip}
\newlength{\@temprightskip}
\newcommand\l@chapter[2]{%
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.46em \@plus\p@  
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode %\bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak%\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
}
\newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0.5in}{1.8em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1in}{2.7em}} 
\newcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{1.5in}{3.6em}}
\newcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\newcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}
\newcommand*\l@bibliography{%
  \vskip 1em \@plus.2\p@\@dottedtocline{0}{0in}{2.3em}
}
\newcommand*\l@bio[2]{%
  \vskip 0.5em \@plus.2\p@
  {%\setlength{\parindent}{0}{#1}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak\makebox[\width]{\normalfont #2}
   \par}
}
\newcommand*\l@table{%
  \vskip 1em \@plus.2\p@\@dottedtocline{0}{0in}{4.9em}
  }
\newcommand\listoftables{%
  \@restonecolfalse
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\linespacingfactor}
  \normalfont 
  \chapter*{\listtablename
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{lot}{\listtablename}{\thepage}}
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
  \normalfont
  \@starttoc{lot}%
  \typeout{\men@me: Bolded LOT}
}
\newcommand*\l@figure{%
  \vskip 1em \@plus.2\p@\@dottedtocline{0}{0in}{5.6em}
  }
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
  \@restonecolfalse
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\linespacingfactor}
  \normalfont
  \chapter*{\listfigurename
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{lof}{\listfigurename}{\thepage}}
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
  \normalfont
  \@starttoc{lof}%
  \typeout{\men@me: Bolded LOF}
}
```

And the .tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[arial,boldheadings,thrmdefs,bbm,ams]{USFDissertation_MODIFIED}

\def\linespacingfactor{2} % use 1 for single and 2 for double line spacing
\def\parindentvalue{1cm} % indentation value

\usepackage[noframe]{showframe} % remove "noframe" option to show the page frames
\usepackage{indentfirst}   % indent all sections
\usepackage{rotating}  % to rotate tables
\usepackage{color,epsfig,subfigure,epstopdf,booktabs,longtable,multirow,wrapfig,url,pdflscape,caption}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}  % output text to absolute position (page numbers on landscape pages)
\usepackage{setspace}           % figures and tables caption line spacing
\captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=1}}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1}}


\allowdisplaybreaks % to allow equations in align brake across pages

\usepackage{lipsum}

%% Begin the document itself
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\linespacingfactor} %
\normalfont

%% Insert a table of contents
\tableofcontents
%% Insert a table of tables -- comes before figures in the format.
\listoftables
%%Insert a table of figures
\listoffigures

%% begin the body of the dissertation
\dissertation

\chapter[\uppercase{Introduction}]{\uppercase{Introduction}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{./figures/Load.eps}\\
  \caption{cap}\label{fig4}
\end{figure}

\chapter[\uppercase{hi}]{\uppercase{hi}}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{The experiment result \label{table_old3}} \centering
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline \textbf{Case} & \textbf{Forecasting Var.}
\\ \hline
1 & 2\\
3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}%

%% End of dissertation
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: We cannot simply make changes in the class file. All redefinitions can be done after loading the class in the document preamble.

Comment: Off topic: `epsfig` is obsolete. `subfigure` is deprecated. You shouldn't use them. (And you shouldn't use explicit mark up in `\chapter[]{}` but correcting that will involve a bit more work.